# Object is property of window (global), window is instance of Object?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, window, instanceof

I'm new in JavaScript. As we know Object is property on window and how can window be an instance of an Object? Are they share some method? And can I create an object like that? Sorry for my English, thank before. :)

```
window.hasOwnProperty("Object"); // return true
window instanceof Object // return true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the global Window object is an Object and can be *thought of* as an instance of an Object, but in JavaScript, this is all *synthesized*.

The tl;dr answer…

Coming to JavaScript from other OO languages such as C++ or Java can be confusing. JavaScript is not a pure OO language in the same way as the other languages. In particular, there is no "class" pure-declaration that passively acts as a template for instances and sub-classes, in the traditional sense. As an interpreted language (rather than a compiled language such as C++ and Java), JavaScript is based on "prototype" functions; class/sub-class relationships are *simulated* by how instances are instantiated and the "chain" of prototype references through the `__proto__` attribute of each function.

Though the `class` keyword has been added to recent JavaScript standards, its implementation is built upon the previously existing mechanism of function definitions and prototype chains. "Sub-classing" can be achieved by setting a function's `prototype` attribute before calling `new` against the function. This will create an object-instance with its `__proto__` attribute defined by the value of the `prototype` attribute.

When looking for member data and methods, if not in the current instance, the chain of `__proto__` attributes are searched for the member until it is found or the end of the chain is reached.